# select query using multiple sqlparameter doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql-server

Here's my code

```
SqlParameter paramUserID = new SqlParameter("@paramUserID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
paramUserID.Value = userID;

SqlParameter paramAccountType = new SqlParameter("@paramAccountType", SqlDbType.Int);
paramAccountType.Value = accountType;

SqlParameter paramSessionID = new SqlParameter("@paramSessionID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
paramSessionID.Value = sessionID;

sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[genericConstants.SVAR_DB_CONN_NAME].ToString());
//for enterprise user, get the permission list for the user
sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT status FROM WSLogin WHERE ([userID] = @paramUserID) AND ([sessionID] = @paramSessionID) AND ([accountType] = @paramAccountType)", sqlConnection);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramUserID);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramAccountType);
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(paramSessionID);

sqlConnection.Open();

reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    returnResult = Int32.Parse(reader["status"].ToString());
}

reader.Close();
```

Status doesn't return anything. but if I copy pasted the value that I pass (`paramUserID, paramAccountType` and `paramSessionID`) and run the query using SQL Server Management Studio I get value 1 for status.

Here's my query in Management Studio

```
SELECT [status] 
FROM [Public].[dbo].[WSLogin] 
WHERE ([userID] = '207') 
  AND ([sessionID] = 'IJiRVkKss14iIDccY8F4ldaV+jNYX7vIeb6IQIlo/78=') 
  AND ([accountType] = 1)
```

Comment: why you don't use an array of SqlParamter to optimize your code and avoid errors relative to single parameters.

Comment: sorry @Dotnetter i don't know how to do that.. can u show me? I'm a noob in C# and mssql

Comment: you're welcome i wrote you an example below

Comment: You're getting a lot of bad answers. Answering @GrantWinney's questions will get you far.

Comment: @GrantWinney i've put a breakpoint on sqlConnection.open. it seems some of the value I passed earlier was wrong. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try using the following way to parameters

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramUserID",paramUserID);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramAccountType",paramAccountType);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramSessionID",paramSessionID);
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: anyway., thanx for Your info regarding AddWithValue(), its looks very  useful